# Difference of rows on one col (Spotfire expression, ipython or python)

Tags: python, expression, ipython

Spotfire difference of previous date and previous period data using python or expression. whatever works. here is the expected output.

```
ID     col End_date    output1            output 2

1      12/2/2020      NaN                NaN
2      11/3/2020      Diff of 1n2        NaN
3      9/5/2020       Diff of 2n3        Diff of1n3 
4      4/21/2020      Diff of3n4         Diff of2n4
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what is your challenge and what exact programming problem you face when trying to overcome it, with your code snippets if applicable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I was able to figure it out using expression.  Getting Previous date difference from one column

Get the RowId()
ParseDate(String([DATE]),"yyyyMMdd") format the date
Max([daDATE]) OVER (Previous([ID],1)) calculate the first date over actual date1
Max([DATE]) OVER (Previous([ID],2)) calculate the first date over actual date2
DateDiff('Day',[DATE],[Max1]) calculate the actual difference date1
DateDiff('Day',[DATE],[Max2]) calculate the actual difference date2

Answer (score 0):

Getting Previous date difference from one column

Get the RowId()

ParseDate(String([date]),"yyyyMMdd") format the date

Max([date]) OVER (Previous([ID],1)) calculate the first date over actual date1

Max([date]) OVER (Previous([ID],2)) calculate the first date over actual date2

DateDiff('Day',[date],[Max1]) calculate the actual difference date1

DateDiff('Day',[date],[Max2]) calculate the actual difference date2